# Android Drag and drop visible/invisible

Tags: android, drag-and-drop

Im using drag and drop to drag a view onto a target. 
Im having a hard time figuring out how to make the original view being dragged invisible while its dragged, and visible again if drag ends, but it is NOT dropped on a target.

```
final TextView dragText1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text_user_drags_1);
dragText1.setOnTouchListener(new MyTouchListener());
final TextView target1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text_target_1);
target1.setOnDragListener(new MyDragListener());


 private final class MyTouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener {
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
            DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(view);
            view.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, view, 0);
           // view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            return true;
        } else {
            //view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            return true;
        }
    }
}
class MyDragListener implements OnDragListener {

    @Override
    public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
        int action = event.getAction();
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:

                TextView draggedView2 = (TextView) event.getLocalState();
                ViewGroup owner1 = (ViewGroup) draggedView2.getParent();
                owner1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                Log.d(TAG, "DRAG STARTED");
                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:

                Log.d(TAG, "DRAG ENTERED");
                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:

                Log.d(TAG, "DRAG EXITED");
                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
                // Dropped, reassign View to ViewGroup
                TextView draggedView = (TextView) event.getLocalState();
                ViewGroup owner = (ViewGroup) draggedView.getParent();
                owner.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                Log.d(TAG, "DRAG DROPPED");
                break;

            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
                if(event.getAction() == DragEvent.ACTION_DROP){
                    TextView draggedView3 = (TextView) event.getLocalState();
                    ViewGroup owner3 = (ViewGroup) draggedView3.getParent();
                    owner3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
                TextView draggedView4 = (TextView) event.getLocalState();
                ViewGroup owner4 = (ViewGroup) draggedView4.getParent();
                owner4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                Log.d(TAG, "DRAG ENDED");
            default:
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the event ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION. On this event, you get the drag X for your view and apply an alpha to the view proportional to the drag percentage. So if your view has been dragged 50% off, you apply an alpha of 0.5; dragged 75%, apply alpha of .25 and so on (alpha = (100f - drag_percent) / 100f